# How to approach a large merge with many conflicts that are not all best handled by the same person?

Tags: git

Say we have a `develop` branch and a `feature` branch. The `develop` branch receives many updates, very frequently, from dozens of developers. It often gets very far ahead of the `feature` branch.

On one occasion, a merge from `develop` into `feature` results in 300 low-level conflicts. These conflicts touch many different areas of the codebase, and no single developer is familiar with all of it. Therefore, it is difficult for any single developer to be able to resolve every conflict on his local machine in order to push a logically correct, conflict-free version of the project.

I understand that the best solution would be to avoid this situation. However, precluding that - due to organizational dysfunction, fait accompli, etc., this situation exists - how best to use git to extricate oneself?

My understanding of git is that it is not possible to commit anything that remains in a conflicted state; by staging, you are indicating that it is not conflicting. Yet, that seems to require that any and all conflicts become the unshared, un-collaborated-upon responsiblity of the person doing the merge. This is undesirable because the conflict resolution is a large task, with parts best handled by separate people.

Two potential ways out occurred to me. However, neither one sounds great. First, I contemplated trying to resolve what conflicts I could, committing those resolutions only, and then leaving other developers to the parts to which they are suited. However, as far as I know, git does not support any kind of interim merge commits, and indeed won't let you begin a merge and subsequently commit unless you locally `add` every conflicted file, thus marking it resolved. I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396358/802517) supports my apprehension.

That led me to my second idea, which was to merely fix what I could, and commit the rest including conflict markers. Fortunately, I was able to resolve all high-level conflicts (file renames/deletions, etc.) but if I hadn't been, those would remain an issue. Setting aside that the `feature` branch would be in a non-compiling state, I am concerned that git would no longer consider these files to be in conflict; it would mean that we would have to rely on our IDEs and other tools to detect the git conflict markers.

My preference would be to only commit files that are actually resolved, allowing other developers to pull them, while files that are not actually resolved remain indicated as conflicted, to them.

I also noticed that there is a `--no-commit` option available to `git merge`, and I am wondering if this is the way to go, since I presume that it would allow me to only commit files I've actually reviewed, understood, and resolved, while leaving the remaining conflicts uncommitted locally.

Is there a more effective strategy to use git to split responsibility for this merge among several developers?

Comment: Either break up the single merge into separate feature branches, or else just pair code during the merge.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by breaking up the single merge?

Comment: Well the premise here is that there is some monolithic pull request containing work from several people, with each piece of work being of a different nature.  Don't do that; instead have each developer work on and push a separate feature branch.  As for your current situation, just get everyone involved in front of the Git bash for 30 minutes and deal with it.

Comment: _"a merge from develop into feature results in 300 low-level conflicts"_ - how though? Do you commit generated code? Do people use squash merges?

Comment: `--no-commit` makes no difference if you are merging and will get conflicts... because if there are conflicts, git won't commit (IOW, that is only relevant if you have merges _without_ conflicts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are ways to *cope* with it... and they are not beautiful. Say, merge on a separate branch that will be used to... let's say, *stabilize* it..... keep a list of the conflicted files. Commit the results *with* conflicts (awful, I know..... it will make sense in the end, continue reading). Let the developers now work on *that* branch to solve the conflicts (provide the list of files, assign who will work on what and so on).... keep on working on this branch (with pull requests, if you dim it necessary).... normal development flow... well, *normal within merge conflict resolution*.

When it is finally stabilized, all conflicts resolved and so on (and here's the beauty of git), just *squash* all revisions used to stabilize it and amend the merge revision to make it look like there was no stabilization process.... it will look like you simply *merged* without any need for stabilization. So... something like:

```
git checkout -b stabilize main
git merge the-other-branch
# you get a gazillion conflicts....
git status > status_merge.txt # keep the list of stuff
git add .
git commit -m "Merging with conflicts.... this is not finished"
# let's set a temporary branch on this revision, so that it is easier to go into the final steps
git branch broken-merge
git push the-remote stabilize
```

Now pass around the list of files to work on and let your developers have fun on top of that branch *until* it is finally resolved.... when it is resolved, you can come back to wrap it up:

```
git fetch the-remote
git checkout the-remote/stabilize
git reset --soft broken-merge # this is your magic wand in action
# now, all the changes that developers had to do to stabilize the branch are in index
git commit --amend -m "Real merge, stabilized"
# and now you have the _real_ results of the merge _replacing_ the old completely broken revision, like it never happened... and you get the credit for it :-)
git branch -f main # let's set main over here... this assumes that main hasn't moved since stabilization started
git push the-remote main
# take a bow
```

And that's it. It's not the most elegant, I agree.... but it would work.

If you would like to **keep** the work that was used to stabilize the branch, I would recommend to create a new revision with the plumbing command that allows us to create them out of thin air, so replacing the second part of the recipe starting with the fetch:

```
git fetch the-remote
git branch temp $( git commit-tree -p main -p the-other-branch -p the-remote/stabilize -m "Merging main and the-feature-branch" the-remote/stabilize^{tree} )
# commit-tree is the plumbing command that creates revisions at will. 
# That command will spit out a revision ID that, thanks to $( )
# we use as input to git branch temp to tell git on what revision
# we want temp to be.
#
# Said revision has main, the-feature-branch _and_
# the-remote/stabilize as parents _and_ has the tree
# (files/contents) of the-remote/stabilize, which is
# the final result of the merge.
#
# if you like how it looks/feels, let's put main over here
git checkout main
git merge temp # this should do a ff to that revision we created
# we can now delete temp
git branch -d temp
git push the-remote main
```

As a final detail, this assumes that main/the-feature-branch do not move while stabilization is taking place..... if that is not the case (the branches do move), then you need a little more work to get it right.

### branches (main, the-feature-branch) do move while stabilization is taking place

In the *first* recipe, second part, it would work like this:

```
git fetch the-remote
git checkout the-remote/stabilize
git reset --soft broken-merge # this is your magic wand in action
# now, all the changes that developers had to do to stabilize the branch are in index
git commit --amend -m "Real merge, stabilized"
git branch temp
# and now you have the _real_ results of the merge _replacing_ the old completely broken revision, like it never happened... and you get the credit for it :-)
# unfortunately main has moved, so we need to _merge_ this into main
git checkout main
git merge the-remote/main # or pull... but we have already fetched recently, right? so no _real_ need to pull
git merge temp # merge the stabilized result of the merge between main and the-feature-branch started back in time
# you might get conflicts coming from the work that was introduced in main after the point where we started to stabilize
# assuming that the merge is finished:
git push the-remote main
# we can now delete temp
git branch -d temp
# take a bow
```

If you are going with the *second* proposal (keeping the stabilization effort in history), the second part of the recipe becomes:

```
git checkout main
git pull # get the contents of main and the new position of the stabilization branch (that is finished, right?)
git branch temp $( git commit-tree -p broken-merge^ -p broken-merge^2 -p the-remote/stabilize -m "Merging main and the-feature-branch" the-remote/stabilize^{tree} )
# just like the previous commit-tree with the recipe with
# main/the-feature-branch not moving _but_ using the
# old positions of main/the-feature-branch as parents
git merge temp # merge back into main.... could get conflicts because of the things that have gone into main since we started to stabilize
# we can now delete temp
git branch -d temp
git push the-remote main
```

Comment: So now you have a branch with 300 files committed with conflict markers, so the project is unrunnable, and you want multiple people working on that to fix only their area of interest, without being able to even validate the result until everyone is done?

Comment: I agree.... I didn't say this is something for the Louvre.

Comment: I think the consensus is that there is no real way out provided by git, so this is essentially the way I'm going.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any *commit* you make after `git merge` *is* the "final result" as far as Git itself is concerned.  That's why [eftshift0 suggests making an extra, bogus, temporary branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658474/1256452) on which you and others build a bunch of temporary results to make progress towards the final real merge.

The way this works in a sort of graphical nutshell is like this:

```
                 ----------
                /          \
       o--...--o   <-- br1  \
      /         \            \
...--*                   \
      \         /              \
       o--...--o   <-- br2      \
                \                \
                 -----------------1--2--3   <-- eww
```

The entire "eww" branch consists of repeated attempts to refine the deliberately-crappy merge whose first attempt is the shreds left by Git at the first scream ().  Once you finally come up with the pile of gold that you're sure must be underneath all that other ... stuff, you return to the attempt to merge `br1` and `br2` again.  You run `git merge` again, which gets all the same conflicts, but then you remove everything and substitute in the files from `n`, which is the pile of gold.

Git badly needs some better tools here.  There *is* [mhagger's imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge), which takes a very different approach and might also be useful here.

Comment: Just want to state that, even though the main concept is the same between my recipe and what you are explaining here (and I do not in any way counter the main idea that it is awful), in my recipe there is no need to run a second merge. You will basically _replace_ (in a way) the original completely-broken, despised and hated merge revision with a completely stabilized (right? hehe) revision by the wonders of `git reset --soft; git commit --amend`)